# Run code on client after helpers

Tags: meteor

How do I initialize a jQuery plugin after helper deliver data for template?

I have the following template:

```blaze
<div class="scrollyeah">
  {{#each projects}}
    {{!-- some data --}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

and client-side code:

```js
Template.templateName.onRendered(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.scrollyeah').scrollyeah();
  });        
});
```

Time to time it works, but sometime I have errors like that:

> Exception from Tracker recompute function: Error: Failed to execute
>   'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this
>   node.

**Update**

Solution is use autorun and wait for subscribtions ready:

```js
Template.templateName.onRendered(function() {
  this.autorun(function() {
    if (Meteor.subscribe('projects').ready()) {
      $('.scrollyeah').scrollyeah();
    }
  });        
});
```

Comment: The initial call is done after the first time the helpers are run.

Answer (score 1):

The initial call is done after the first time the helpers are run.

It is not likely that those errors can be fixed without messing with Blaze internals.

The jQuery plugin changes the DOM structure, so when a re-computation is done (possibly due to a change in the cursor that is returned by `projects`), Blaze does not find the structure that is expected (e.g, a *project* is to be removed and the related node is no longer a child of the `.scrollyeah` div).

It is also possible that the helpers are re-run after the template has rendered in case the subscription did not have all of the data. You can take care of this by only rendering the list once the subscription is ready, but this won't solve your issue.

Be careful when dealing with jQuery plugins that change the DOM in such a way.

BTW, wrapping it with `$(document).ready` is probably redundant.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I thought it's has a common pattern in a Meteor practice for issues like this. I just use `setTimeout`, but it's uhhh ugly.

Comment: And it is error-prone, if your cursor changes after the timeout expires. You should probably find a less intrusive plugin or hack it such that it does not change the DOM structure (e.g, provide the required structure in your template and change the plugin source to cope with that).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put this inside autorun. Use template.autorun instead of Tracker.autorun because template.autorun is stopped when the template is destroyed. [See Meteor Docs.](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun)

> Run a function now and rerun it later whenever its dependencies change. Returns a Computation object that can be used to stop or observe the rerunning.

```
Template.templateName.onRendered(function() {
  this.autorun(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.scrollyeah').scrollyeah();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Nothing changes, same output with autorun.